# mongodb error. how can I solve the erro in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: test

```
2016-05-08T10:46:12.023+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-05-08T10:46:12.023+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have the mongodb service running? Run `sudo service mongod status` and see what it returns. If it is stopped, run `sudo service mongod start` to start the mongodb and try connecting to it.

You can also, check whether the mongodb is listening on 27017 or not by running: `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 27017`.

If `sudo service mongod start` is giving a error, you may need to check the configuration. We can help you better if you can post the output of the above commands.

**Update**:

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Hi Ravi not working 
sudo service mongod start
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I think, Default init system is systemd now and the upstart(which was used previously) is removed. I have updated the answer, to create a service file for systemd. Give it a try.

Comment: Note: Make sure you have set the `data directory` inside the mongodb.conf file.

Comment: @mohamedzajith For Ubuntu 16, you need to create `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service` instead of `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` as shown in the answer.
And run `sudo systemctl start mongodb` to start and `sudo systemctl enable mongodb` to start automatically every time.

Reference https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

Just restart the service in terminal, verbose mode helps you to understand the background configuration

```
$brew services restart  mongodb --verbose
```

and open another terminal (don't use same terminal) and type **mongod**, you should be able to see process running.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse have the same problem . Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS . The installation process , the same as in the official website of mongo . When I do:

sudo service mongod status; appear

`● mongod.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

I guess the error will be in the configuration of "data directory" and the port, but not as configure it properly

Answer (score -1):

Fork your mongodb process as a daemon so that it keeps running in background. E.g

```
./mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /home/db_directory --logpath /logs/mongod.log --fork
```